# How does Chrome's garbage collector handle async functions that never return a value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, async-await, chromium, v8

Does this cause any issues? I'd guess not, as long as we don't attempt to `await` an async function without a return value?

I've been looking for information on this, and I'm sure it's out there (maybe even obvious) but I haven't had any luck finding a definitive answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "never"? Do you just mean that they don't `return` any value? Then just like normal function, the return value defaults to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector has nothing to do with it.

In JavaScript, every function returns a value. When it has no explicit `return` statement, it'll implicitly return `undefined`.

Of course, if you wait for an event that never happens, you'll end up waiting forever. Any callbacks registered to run when the event happens will wait with you, i.e. they'll stay in memory forever.

See for yourself:

```
async function foo() { /* no explicit return */ }
let result = await foo();
console.log(result);  // undefined
```